# Post request using Json and javascript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, json, post, request

I want to take the value of each `<input/>` and send it as a JSON request.

Here is the form.

```
<form class="formidable">
      <p>Date, heure et lieu de naissance</p>
      <input type="text" name="day" id="day" placeholder="Jour">
      <input type="text" name="month" id="month" placeholder="Mois">
      <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Année">
      <input type="text" name="hour" id="hour" placeholder="Heure">
      <input type="text" name="minutes" id="minutes" placeholder="minutes">
      <input type="text" name="birthCity" placeholder="Ville">
      <input type="text" name="birthCountryLabel" placeholder="Pays">
      <input type="text" name="birthCountryCode" placeholder="Code postal">
      <input type="submit" name="button" value="submit" id="signin-login" onclick="GameJs()">
  </form>
```

Here is what I already tried: (I've set all the variable first)

```
function GameJs() {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', 'url');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
        else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(encodeURI(day));
    alert(birthCity);
}
```

I get a response from my server, but I can't send my `<input/>` values.

Comment: Can we know how did you set the variable "day"?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are new to the site, but I would request you to look into the existing questions and answers before posting a new question.

From your question and code, it seems that you want to pass the entire form to the post request. To get the form data, you can use the following:

```
var data= new FormData(document.querySelector('form'))
```

This is a html5 feature. You can pass the `data` to the POST and you should get all the data in your back end.

Comment: its a query selector and i can't use it :/ Thank you for the response !

Comment: in that case you can get all the input data using `document.getElementById()` and create a json object yourself using the name of the elements. Sending this json into the request should do the trick..cheers

Comment: added a different answer

Comment: Thank you dude ! i give you my feedback as soon as i can i'm trying to do it right now

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your JS function like:

```
function GameJs(){
    var day = document.getElementById('day');
    var month = document.getElementById('month');
    var year = document.getElementsByName('year')[0];
    var hour = document.getElementById('hour');
    var minutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
    var birthCity = document.getElementsByName('birthCity')[0];
    var birthCountryLabel = document.getElementsByName('birthCountryLabel')[0];
    var birthCountryCode = document.getElementsByName('birthCountryCode')[0];

    var x = {};
      x[day.name.toString()]= day.value;
      x[month.name.toString()]= month.value;
      x[year.name.toString()]= year.value;
      x[hour.name.toString()]= hour.value;
      x[minutes.name.toString()]= minutes.value;
      x[birthCity.name.toString()]= birthCity.value;
      x[birthCountryLabel.name.toString()]= birthCountryLabel.value;
      x[birthCountryCode.name.toString()]= birthCountryCode.value;
    console.log(x);
    //your post code here, post the variable x as the data
    return false;
}
```

and at the html, edit the submit button as

```
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="submit" id="signin-login" onclick="return GameJs()">
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ur1j2ey8/1/)

Comment: Thank you dude, i'm gonna try this out ! i give you a comment back if this worked, but looks exactly like what i wanted to !